# Baixar imagem gerada

Tags: javascript, html

Quero por no meu site a opção de baixar alguns dados de um formulário como imagem. No meu código atual eu transformo o conteúdo em imagem, mas ela é impressa no HTML.

Aqui o código simplificado no JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gor263yw/

Tudo que preciso agora é que esta imagem gerada seja automaticamente baixada ao clicar em "GERAR", e não apareça no html!

podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o jquery para criar e adicionar o elemento no `DOM` eu adicionei o seguinte codigo ao seu script e no teste funcionou, talvez isso te ajude.

```
a = $("<a>").attr({href:dataUrl,download:'image.jpeg'}).html("OLA");
$("body").append(a);
a.get(0).click();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gor263yw/3/

Comment: amigo, muitíssimo obrigado! funciona muito bem como eu precisava.